# ORA-12154: TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified (but Net Manager tests fine!)

Tags: oracle12c, ora-12154

I am running Lyris ListManager on a Win 2008 server. It connects to Oracle 12c on another machine.

I have successfully configured and tested the connection using the Net Manger (or Net Configuration Assistant). However, when I run ListManger, I receive this Oracle error (TNS: could not resolve the connect identifier specified).

I checked the configuration file for the ListManager (lmcfg.txt), which correctly specifies everything.

Previously, we had Oracle 11g database, and 11g client on this server, which worked fine. DB upgrade to 12c was successful (other applications, on other servers, work fine), and I removed 11g client and installed 12c. It successfully connects to the Oracle server with the correct service ID, but Lyris ListManger application can't connect.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems ListManager doesn't find the correct TNSNAMES.ORA that is defining the service name. Check if ListManager is looking for the new Oracle12 location of tnsnames.ora. If ita path name is based on an environment variable (e.g. %ORACLE_HOME% ) check it has been updated with oracle12 path name.

Comment: After a lot of poking around, I discovered that the problem was with the ODBC driver. At some point during the process of trying to figure this out, I had installed (and subsequently uninstalled) 64-bit Oracle client. Apparently, ODBC was still pointing to the path to that (uninstalled) 64-bit client. I added a new driver, which points to the correct path, and as soon as I did that, ListManger was able to connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root of the problem was in multiple client installations. At some point during the troubleshooting, I installed, and then uninstalled 64-bit client. After that, I installed 32-bit client and got it to connect through the Net Manager. However, that 64-bit client wasn't correctly and completely removed, and the ODBC driver was still looking at its original path for DLL libraries (which weren't there anymore).

I had to add a new ODBC driver entry for the 32-bit Oracle client. Once this was properly configured, the ListManager application was able to connect to Oracle server.